# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null". I am not able to solve it

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

**I am not able to solve the problem --> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
I have it implemented like this:**

```
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
        public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        
            private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
            private final PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository;
        
            // needed for use with Spring Data JPA SPeL
            @Bean
            public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
                return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
                http
                        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> {
                            authorize
                                    .antMatchers("/", "/webjars/**", "/login", "/resources/**").permitAll();
                        } )
                        .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .formLogin(loginConfigurer -> {
                            loginConfigurer
                                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                                    .loginPage("/").permitAll()
                                    .successForwardUrl("/")
                                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                                    .failureUrl("/?error");
                        })
                        .logout(logoutConfigurer -> {
                            logoutConfigurer
                                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout", "GET"))
                                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                                    .permitAll();
                        })
                        .httpBasic()
                        .and().rememberMe()
                        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository)
                        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
                http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
            }
        
            @Bean
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
                return SfgPasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
            }
```

**Token creation**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityBeans {
    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository(DataSource dataSource){
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepository;
    }

}

****************************************************************************************************
```

**In the DB insert a password in bcrypt for the user. The error seems to be in return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(encodingId, encoders); but I think it's fine.**

```
public class SfgPasswordEncoderFactories {

    public static PasswordEncoder createDelegatingPasswordEncoder() {
        String encodingId = "bcrypt";
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put(encodingId, new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("ldap", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.LdapShaPasswordEncoder());
        encoders.put("noop", org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        encoders.put("sha256", new org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder());

        return new DelegatingPasswordEncoder(encodingId, encoders);
    }

    //don't instantiate class
    private SfgPasswordEncoderFactories() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace too.

Comment: Your passwords in the database are probably not prepended with what decoder to use `{bcrypt}mySecretHashedPassword` if you fetch a hashed password from the database how is the service going to know what encoder was used? You need to prefix the passwords with the name of the encoding schema inside brackets

Comment: Have you tried just using `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()` instead? Out of curiosity, why are you creating a custom delegating password encoder? It looks like you just support fewer than the provided one but don't customize anything about them.

Comment: Also see @Toerktumlare comment which I agree with. Please also show how you are encoding the passwords for the database.